# In two verbs I want to omit one and convey the meaning of recognition using Do

Tags: verbs

For example:

> Whether the doctor knows me or not but she knows me

Should I make the second clause  something as' *Whether the doctor knows me or not but she does me.' Is this way correct to use and conveys the meaning of the same as above the example

Comment: your sentence doesn't make sense - what are you trying to say?

Comment: Whether the doctor knows me or not but she knows me. I mean It's uncertain that the doctor knows me but , she for sure knows me I want to avoid 'Know' and use 'Do' instead of it

Comment: still not making sense...'do' and 'know' aren't really closely related words

Comment: The sentence isn't very clear to me as it stands.  It might make more sense if it had  something else at the start e.g. 'It is possible to get an appointment whether the doctor knows me or not...'  I would probably say 'and she does' in this context. (which implies 'and she does know me')

Answer (score 1):

You could be clearer with something like -

> Whether the doctor knows me or not, but *she for sure* knows me

Or

> *Whether or not* the doctor knows me, but she *definitely does*

Comment: @ShaheenBano an even nicer way to thank a user is to accept their answer, this shows everyone you are satisfied, and your question has been  answered. Click on the grey checkmark under the arrow, which should change it into green.

Comment: @ShaheenBano, i agree with Mari-Lou! :p